JSON to CSV using php, but prevent saving file on server
We use the following php code to transform JSON to CSV, that works fine. But it will also create a file named download.csv that will be downloaded. Is there a way to build and download a .csv all on browser visitor level, without creating a real .csv that's stored on our own server?
<?php
function convertJsonToCSV($jsonString, $csvFile)
{
    $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    $fp = fopen($csvFile, 'w');
    $header = false;
    foreach ($jsonArray as $line) {
        if (empty($header)) {
            $header = array_keys($line);
            fputcsv($fp, $header);
            $header = array_flip($header);
        }
        fputcsv($fp, array_merge($header, $line));
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return;
}
$jsonString = '[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Lion",
        "Type": "Wild",
        "Role": "Lazy Boss"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Tiger",
        "Type": "Wild",
        "Role": "CEO"
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Name": "Jaguar",
        "Type": "Wild",
        "Role": "Developer"
    }
]';
$csvFile = 'download.csv';

convertJsonToCSV($jsonString, $csvFile);
echo 'JSON to CSV converted. <a href="' . $csvFile . '" target="_blank">Download CSV file</a>';

EDIT:
$jsonString = '[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Lion",
        "Type": "Wild",
        "Role": "Lazy Boss"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Tiger",
        "Type": "Wild",
        "Role": "CEO"
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Name": "Jaguar",
        "Type": "Wild",
        "Role": "Developer"
    }
]';
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$header = false;
foreach ($jsonArray as $line) {
    if (empty($header)) {
        $header = array_keys($line);
        fputcsv($fp, $header);
        $header = array_flip($header);
    }
    fputcsv($fp, array_merge($header, $line));
}
fclose($fp);
return;


You can use a memory stream, as shown here.

@Olivier You can use php://output directly without buffering it in memory.

@Olivier Thanks! But is there a way to transform this into a html link element, to really download it?

If you want a two step process in which you output a link for a separate download, then you'll need to store something somewhere. Either store the uploaded file and output the CSV on the fly, or produce the CSV directly after upload and store it somewhere. — If you don't want to store any files anywhere, you'll need to process the uploaded file immediately and immediately respond with the CSV data.

@deceze The JSON output is directly trough PHP, so we want to create a download button, to download these JSON values into a CSV. So a two step process is required, because the download should not be processed directly on load.

Well, then you gotta store something somewhere.

@deceze Thanks! See my edit, but this does not download the CSV directly on page load using php://output. What am I missing here?

What's that mean? What does it do? What exactly did you expect instead?

@deceze I expected it should create a csv file and download it. But it does not create and download a csv with this edit.

…‍♂️ What does it do? It outta do something. If it doesn't, debug it (e.g. by adding some echo statements) to see what it does and where it stops.

@deceze Sorry, it does echo the values as plain values in the browser, instead of generating a csv and download it.

Then see the second duplicate linked above.

@deceze Thanks! Tried that also, but that does download the entire page as csv, instead of the code itself

And what does that mean? Are you trying to serve a web page and download a CSV file in one response? Yeah, that ain't gonna work.
